# Creating clickable link from form variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, hyperlink

Working with a dynamic page that 
1. generates a list of files in the folder
2. makes a selection box of that list
3. Provides a clickable link to selected file

Steps 1 and 2 working like a charm, but I just can't seem to pass that variable through and make it a clickable link.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// Step 3. Create clickable link from selection
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$optionVal = $_POST[$file];
echo '<a href="'.$optionVal.'">Click to download: <strong>'.$optionVal.'</strong></a>';
} else {

// Step 1: Get file listing 
$show_path = 1;   # Show local path.
$show_dotdirs = 1;   # Show '.' and '..'.
$path = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '/') + 1);

$dirs = array();
$files = array();

$dir = dir($path);
while ($entry = $dir->read()) {
    if (($entry != '.') and (substr($entry, -4) != '.php')) {
        if (is_dir($entry)) {
            if (($entry != '..') or $show_dotdirs){
                $dirs[] = $entry;
            }
        } else {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }
}
$dir->close();
?>
<form action="pagelist.php" method="post">
<label>Select your lab: <select name="lab">
<?php
// Step 2: Make file listing in to selection box
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo('<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>');
}
?>
</select></label>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go">

</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
$optionVal = $_POST[$file];
```

Into:

```
$optionVal = $_POST['lab'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$optionVal = $_POST[$file];` is your problem.  This should probably be `$optionVal = $_POST['lab'];`